# Android Studio ingresar mas datos a usuario específico

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Buen día,

Ingreso con el usuario y llamo dos datos desde una url y los muestro en textviews, estos datos como los envío a firebase dentro el mismo usuario registrado? Tengo lo siguiente para el envío al firebases pero me sale error:

ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.jhonfregom.egps.GPSActivity.guardarcoord(GPSActivity.java:160)
        at com.example.jhonfregom.egps.GPSActivity.access$000(GPSActivity.java:51)
        at com.example.jhonfregom.egps.GPSActivity$1.onClick(GPSActivity.java:95)

```js
package com.example.jhonfregom.egps;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import locat.devazt.networking.HttpClient;
import locat.devazt.networking.OnHttpRequestComplete;
import locat.devazt.networking.Response;

public class GPSActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    String ubicacion;
    String direccion;
    String ciudad;
    double longitud, latitud;
    TextView txtubicacion;
    Button verMapa;
    Button iniciogps, detenergps, guardargps;
    private Button mLogoutBtn;
    TextView txtubicacion2;
    TextView txtubicacion3;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private RequestQueue mPosicion;
    private RequestQueue mPosicionF;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    Localizacion local;
    static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);

        mLogoutBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        iniciogps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inicio);
        detenergps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.detener);
        guardargps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.guardar);
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        txtubicacion2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtubicacion2);
        txtubicacion3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtubicacion3);

        mPosicion = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        mPosicionF = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        guardargps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                guardarcoord();
            }
        });

        iniciogps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                jsonParse();
            }
        });


        detenergps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                jsonParseF();
            }
        });

        mLogoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(GPSActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    private void guardarcoord() {
        final String datos = "0.125555";
        final String mPosicionIni = txtubicacion2.getText().toString().trim();
        final String mPosicionfin = txtubicacion3.getText().toString().trim();
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    //    try{
        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = mDatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    databaseReference.child("datos").setValue(datos);
                    databaseReference.child("Posicion Inicial").setValue(mPosicion);
                    databaseReference.child("Posicion Final").setValue(mPosicionF);
                    Toast.makeText(GPSActivity.this, "Ubicación grabada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(GPSActivity.this, "Error al grabar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };//}//catch(Exception e){
          //  e.printStackTrace();
        //}
    }


private void jsonParse() {
      //   String url = "http://192.168.43.109/gpio/1";
       // String url = "http://192.168.0.17/gpio/1";
        String url = "http://api.myjson.com/bins/p498q";


        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("coordenadas");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject coordi = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String latitud = coordi.getString("latitud");
                                String longitud = coordi.getString("longitud");
                                txtubicacion2.append(latitud + "," +longitud +" ");

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mPosicion.add(request);
    }

private void jsonParseF() {
        //  String url = "http://192.168.43.109/gpio/1";
     //   String  url= "https://api.myjson.com/bins/ib6pm";
     //   String url = "http://192.168.0.17/gpio/1";
        String url = "http://api.myjson.com/bins/p498q";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("coordenadas");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject coordf = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String latitud = coordf.getString("latitud");
                                String longitud = coordf.getString("longitud");
                                txtubicacion3.append(latitud + "," +longitud +" ");

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mPosicionF.add(request);
    }

}
```

Comment: No se puede ser por el tipo de mPosicion que es requestQueue?? De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Cual es la linea 160 de GPSActivity.java ? según el código es esta línea:               JSONObject coordi = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); verifica en realidad donde se produce el error

Comment: la linea 160 es  final DatabaseReference databaseReference = mDatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

Comment: Ve la primera parte de mi respuesta, intercambia las líneas. @JhonFreddyGomezFranco

Answer (score 0):

Intercambia estas lineas de posición ya que debes obtener antes el valor de mAuth:

```
  final DatabaseReference databaseReference = mDatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

por:

```
  mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  final DatabaseReference databaseReference = mDatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

De acuerdo a tu código estas obteniendo la instancia aquí:

```
mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

por lo tanto debes usar esta instancia:

```
 ...
 ...
 //if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) { //Incorrecto
 if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
 ...
 ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, hice lo que me dices y ya no hay errores al darle grabar, pero no envía los datos.

Comment: @JhonFreddyGómezFranco en este caso es importante revises  aquí:  DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users"); si mDatabase  obtiene datos.

Comment: como puedo verificar si tiene datos? tiene algo que ver que sea un json visualizados de textviews???

Answer (score 0):

@Jorgesys Modifiqué lo que me indicaste pero aún no me da ejecución o error cuando le doy grabar.

EL onclick lo tengo asi:

```js
       guardargps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                guardarcoord();
            }
        });
```

y ya corregido como me indicaste asi:

```js
private void guardarcoord() {
        final String mPosicionIni = txtubicacion2.getText().toString().trim();
        final String mPosicionfin = txtubicacion3.getText().toString().trim();
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
 
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = mDatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        mAuthListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    databaseReference.child("Posicion Inicial").setValue(mPosicionIni);
                    databaseReference.child("Posicion Final").setValue(mPosicionfin);
                    Toast.makeText(GPSActivity.this, "Ubicación grabada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(GPSActivity.this, "Error al grabar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
    }
```

No se si el onclick no lo está enlazando, o me falta algo? no me sale algún error esta vez.

Muchas gracias.